# Create list of tuples with data from nested lists with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects which contains a list of other objects.

```
List<Parent> Ps;
```

Parent:

```
class Parent 
{
   List<Childs> Cs;
}
```

Is there a possibility to create with Linq a list of tuples of parents and childs?

```
Tuple<Parent, Child>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<Tuple<Parent, Child>> parentChilds = Ps
    .SelectMany(p => p.Cs.Select(c => Tuple.Create(p, c)))
    .ToList();
```

This is equal to this:

```
var pcQuery = from parent in Ps
              from child in parent.Cs
              select Tuple.Create(parent, child);
List<Tuple<Parent, Child>> parentChilds = pcQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for including comprehension and lambda syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
var tuples = from p in Ps from c in p.Cs select Tuple.Create(p, c);
```